# pandasでうまくデータを追加できません。

Tags: python, pandas

pandasで、データを追加したいのですが、どうすればいいのかが分かりません。
appendで出来るのかと思ったのですが、コラムで指定したデータに入れたいデータが入りません。
0がラベル名になって、pandasで縦にデータが並んでしまいます。
私は、columnsで指定したラベル名にリストを入れたいのです。
listの順番と、コラムの指定の順番は同じになっています。

```
data_set_list = [10,1,2]
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=["V", "I", "1"])
a.append(data_set_inst)
```

データフレームを空で用意せずに直で入れればいいじゃないかと言うのはそうなのですが、
実際のコードでは、listとなるデータを追加で入れていく形にしたいので、追加できるようにしたいのです。

追記

```
data_set_list = []

data_set_list.append(x)  

df = pd.DataFrame(data_set_list,
                  columns=['V', 'I', '1'])
```

appendの部分は、for文で繰り返す予定ですが、
このような感じ宜しいのでしょうか？

Comment: `a.loc[len(a)] = data_set_list`

Comment: ちなみに途中の処理はすべてリストで行って、最後にまとめてDataFrameにするのでは駄目なのでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。言われてみれば、確かに最後にまとめてdataframeにする方がいいです。

Answer (score 1):

辞書(dict)に変換して追加する方法

```py
import pandas as pd

data_set_list = [10,1,2]
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=["V", "I", "1"])
for _ in range(1000):
    a = a.append(dict(zip(a.columns, data_set_list)), ignore_index=True)

display(a)
```

---

(念の為)
pandasで一つ一つデータ追加していくと遅いので
可能なら, list or dictでデータを蓄えたほうがよいかも (最後に DataFrameに一括変換)

---

##### 追記

list で蓄える場合

```py
data_set_list = []
for n in range(1000):
    data_set_list.append([10,n,2])

df = pd.DataFrame(data_set_list,
                  columns=['V', 'I', '1'])
df
#       V   I   1
#  0    10  0   2
#  1    10  1   2
#  2    10  2   2
#  3    10  3   2
#  4    10  4   2
#...    ... ... ...
#995    10  995 2
#996    10  996 2
#997    10  997 2
#998    10  998 2
#999    10  999 2
#1000 rows × 3 columns
```

Answer (score 0):

リストを`Series`に変換すると行を追加できます。

```
import pandas as pd

data_set_list = [10,1,2]
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=["V", "I", "1"])
series = pd.Series(data_set_list, index=a.columns)
a.append(series, ignore_index=True)
print(a)

#    V  I  1
#0  10  1  2
```

参考資料:
[pandas.DataFrameに１行ずつ書き足す早い方法を調べた](https://qiita.com/studio_haneya/items/35951c56decd212ba41e)
[pandas.DataFrameに列や行を追加（assign, appendなど）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-assign-append/)