# pandasのデータフレームにappendしながら、追加した行の名前を変えたい

Tags: python, pandas

pandasのデータフレーム`df`に１行ずつデータを追加しながら、その１行の行名を指定（変更）したいと思っています。変更しなくてもよい行もあるので、実際のソースでは、`df.rename`を`if`でくくっています。ソースコードのイメージは、以下の通りです。

```py
for i in range(0, 100):
    df = df.append(dict(zip(list_colname, list_data)), ignore_index=True)
    if 名前を変える？
        df = df.rename(index={int(len(df)) - 1: 'test' + str(len(df))})
```

ただし、

- `list_colname` : 列名のリスト
- `list_data` : `list_colname`に対応した、データのリスト

という感じのことをやりたいと思っています。実行した結果を見ると、`df`の末尾の行のみ、意図したとおりの行名（`'test' + str(len(df))`）に変更されていますが、それ以前の行は連番になっています。

データフレームの上書きというかデータフレームの更新というか（`append`をやる都度、前回までのデータが消えてしまっている？）、そういうのが何かうまくっていない気がします。どういうソースを書いたらよいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: プログラムコードを示す際は全角スペースのインデントは止めたほうがよいでしょう。(回答者が)確認のためにコピペして実行しようとするかもしれなくて, 余計なトラブルやノイズになります

Comment: `ignore_index=True` を指定すると, index名を無視し(ignore), 新たな番号が割り振られます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

行を挿入する前に index の名前を変更しておく方法も考えられます。以下の例では `a` 列の値が偶数の場合に index の名前を変更しています。

```py
import pandas as pd

list_colname = ('a', 'b', 'c')
list_data = (
  (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9),
  (10, 11, 12), (13, 14, 15), (16, 17, 18),
)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_colname)
for data in list_data:
  df.loc[('' if data[0] % 2 else 'test') + str(len(df))] = data
```

###### `print(df.to_markdown())`

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| test1 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| test3 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 4 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| test5 | 16 | 17 | 18 |

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、
df.loc[Name] = dict(zip(list_colname, list_data))
でできました。

Answer (score 1):

dictで追加するのではなく pandas.Series で追加すると良いでしょう

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(10):
    ser = pd.Series([100, 200, 300],
        index=['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        name=f'id_{i}' if i %3 == 0 else i*2)
    df = df.append(ser)

display(df)
```

というより, 1行ずつ DataFrameにデータを追加というのは遅くなるので, できれば止めたほうがよいような
(dict や list で管理したほうがよさそう)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
実は私も当初は、seriesでやっていたのですが、列名を合わせて追加することができず、ちょうど下記のような投稿を見つけたので、そのまま使いました。ほかに良い方法はあるでしょうか？

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/82512/pandas%e3%81%a7%e3%81%86%e3%81%be%e3%81%8f%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92%e8%bf%bd%e5%8a%a0%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93